# Why I get 404 when I using ecs-cli?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I'm using `ecs-cli` to deploy my `docker-compose.yml` to ecs with SSL support.

When I run the command it's show me that the container is running. but when I browse to url is show me 404 error.

why?

this is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '2'
services:
  tester-cluster:
    image: yeasy/simple-web:latest
    environment:
      VIRTUAL_HOST: mydomin.net
      LETSENCRYPT_HOST: mydomin.net
      LETSENCRYPT_EMAIL: mydomin@gmail.com

  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    volumes:
      - '/etc/nginx/vhost.d'
      - '/usr/share/nginx/html'
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro'
      - '/etc/nginx/certs'

  letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    volumes:
      - '/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro'
    volumes_from:
      - 'nginx-proxy'
```

Comment: Are you browsing with your EC2 host Url?. In order to nginx-proxy to work, you will need to pass `mydomain.net` as [Host](https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy#docker-compose) header in HTTP request. If you are also passing Host header properly and still getting 404 then let me know. I was able to replicate the 404 error at my end as well because I was connected to VPN/Proxy which was intercepting HTTP requests and actually trying to route the traffic to Host(not EC2).

Comment: I browse with mydomain.net

Answer (score 0):

You will have to set the `WORDPRESS_DB_HOST` for the wordpress server as well. This will be something similar to the following:

```
WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: mysql:3306
```

Note the host name would be the name of the db container.

You can view container logs by running the following:

```
docker-compose logs -f -t
```

Comment: not working also after I add DB_HOST. I don't think it because DB_HOST, maybe, but I update my question. still not working..